# Use Laravel seed and sql files to populate database

Tags: laravel-4

I got several .sql files of countries, states and cities of the world from github.  How can I run them with Laravel's seed files to populate those tables in my database?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

1. Add `DB::unprepared()` to the run method of `DatabaseSeeder`.
2. Run `php artisan db:seed` at the command line.

   ```
   class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

       public function run()
       {
           Eloquent::unguard();

           $this->call('UserTableSeeder');
           $this->command->info('User table seeded!');

           $path = 'app/developer_docs/countries.sql';
           DB::unprepared(file_get_contents($path));
           $this->command->info('Country table seeded!');
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Another thing you can use is this converter: http://laravel.stonelab.ch/sql-seeder-converter/ - though it didn't handle well large SQL files. You can also export and use your IDE's search and replace to prepare it for you. Otherwise, follow what @AndrewKoper suggested.

Comment: phpMyAdmin add some stuff to sql file like `SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
` - get rid of it if doesn't work

Comment: This solution does not work with more complex .SQL files and your migration will exit without errorhaving only half of the file completed. A better solution is to use MySQL cli command

Comment: In my case, this solution only works if you leave the insert statement alone. You should get rid of all the code that has been dumped other than INSERT statement. It doesn't work if you try to run mysql dump as it is.

Answer (score 15):

I found a package that creates seed files from database tables and rows. It currently supports Laravel 4 through 10:

https://github.com/orangehill/iseed

In the end, it's basically as easy as this:

```
php artisan iseed my_table
```

or for multiple occasions:

```
php artisan iseed my_table,another_table
```

Answer (score 5):

2022 Simplified answer from Andrew Koper :

```php
class WhateverSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $file_path = resource_path('sql/whatever.sql');

        \DB::unprepared(
            file_get_contents($file_path)
        );
    }
}
```

Fun fact: 60,000 rows took me 50s to import from JSON file where this took only 400ms.

Answer (score 4):

As used by other answers, `DB::unprepared` **does not** work with more complex SQL files.

Another better solution would be to use the MySQL cli directly inside a process:

```
$process = new Process([
            'mysql',
            '-h',
            DB::getConfig('host'),
            '-u',
            DB::getConfig('username'),
            '-p' . DB::getConfig('password'),
            DB::getConfig('database'),
            '-e',
            "source path/to/schema.sql"
        ]);
        $process->mustRun();
```

Answer (score 2):

@Andre Koper solutions is understandable, but sadly it doesn't work for me. 
This one is a bit confusing but atleast works for me.

So instead of using DB::unprepared, I use this:

```
// DatabaseSeeder.php
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
       // Set the path of your .sql file
       $sql = storage_path('a_id_territory.sql');

       // You must change this one, its depend on your mysql bin.
       $db_bin = "C:\wamp64\bin\mariadb\mariadb10.3.14\bin";

       // PDO Credentials
       $db = [
           'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
           'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
           'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
           'database' => env('DB_DATABASE')
       ];
       exec("{$db_bin}\mysql --user={$db['username']} --password={$db['password']} --host={$db['host']} --database {$db['database']} < $sql");
    }
}
```

Then while migrating database just add --seed

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

or

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

**Tested on Laravel 7.0.x**