# How do I seed laravel from sql file(contains links to other sql files)

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-seeding

I have two files

`employees.sql`

```sql
SELECT 'CREATING DATABASE STRUCTURE' as 'INFO';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employees_test;

CREATE TABLE employees_test (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
    first_name  VARCHAR(14)     NOT NULL,
    last_name   VARCHAR(16)     NOT NULL,
    hire_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no)
);

SELECT 'LOADING employees_test' as 'INFO';
source employees.dump
```

`employees.dump`

```sql
INSERT INTO `employees_test` VALUES (10001,'Georgi','Facello','1986-06-26');
```

This seeder doesn't work

```php
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class EmployeesSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
    $sql = base_path('database/seeds/temp/employees.sql');
    DB::unprepared(file_get_contents($sql));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use Laravel migrations instead of raw SQL?

Comment: Because I already have sql dump and don't want to port it to migrations

Comment: Does it work if you put the full path to employees.dump in the source statement?

Comment: Unfortunatelly doesn't work

Comment: Does [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369452/use-laravel-seed-and-sql-files-to-populate-database#comment96291707_37381991) help?

Comment: It can't help because I don't have this comment in my dump.