# seed Table in Laravel using sqllite file

Tags: laravel, sqlite, migration

I am working on a Laravel project, I have records in a sqlLite file and I want to seed those records into pre-defined migrated table. How can I achieve that. Should I read the file and iterate through each value or there is a simpler way to do so?

I have tried this solution but it didn't work with me.([Use Laravel seed and sql files to populate database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369452/use-laravel-seed-and-sql-files-to-populate-database))

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, this is how I solved it:
Do something like this in your seeder:

```
public function run()
{
    $db_file_path = base_path('/db/erz.db');
    if(!file_exists($db_file_path) || !is_readable($db_file_path))
        return false;
    $db = new SQLite3($db_file_path);
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM locations');
    while($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
        Location::create([
            'zip' => $row['zip'],
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'geocode_name' => $row['geocode_name'],
            'latitude' => $row['latitude'],
            'longitude' => $row['longitude'],
            'services' => $row['services']
        ]);
    }
}
```

You will have to alter the query and for this to work, you have to have a model. But does not really matter since you are going to need one anyway ;-)

Hope that helps!